# Add second ip address to an existing SQl 2008 failover clustering

Tags: networking, sql-server-2008, cluster, failover, failovercluster

I have a failover cluster on Windows Server 2008, with SQL server 2008.

On each server I have two network cards, with two different networks.  One is on 10.10.10.x and the other is on 192.168.99.x

I want my sqlserver cluster to listen on both networks. Is it possible and how do I add a new ip address?

When I add a new IP address directly in the cluster, and I telnet to the 1433 port with the new cluster IP address it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's working, but we need to wait before the failover work

Comment: Can you please expand on how you got it working for us?